# Problem extending jog4j RollingFileAppender rollOver() access Level

Tags: java, logging, log4j, access-modifiers

I am trying to extend RollingFileAppender so that it will rotate even when no messages are coming into the logging system. Normally the rollOver method is called when a message arrives and a time check is done to trigger the rotate.

My Version of RollingFileAppender will call rollOver every x seconds so that I am guaranteed a rotate even when no messages arrive.

Now my problem is that RollingFileAppender rollOver has an Access level modifier of no modifier. Thus I can't call it every x seconds like I wish to.

```
  /**
     Rollover the current file to a new file.
  */
  void rollOver() throws IOException {
```

Now looking at the code I can't figure out why it requires no modifer and I have decided to bring the class into my packages and call rollOver.

Now this feels dirty do I have any other alternatives if I want to call rollOver?

Comment: Which version of log4j do you use? It is public in the one I am using 1.2.14 and also in the latest 1.2.15.

Comment: 1.2.15 I pasted the code above out of the source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course do it using reflection.

Source code extracted from the trunk or from tag 1.2.15 : [svn at apache](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/tags/v1_2_15/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.java?view=markup)

```
public // synchronization not necessary since doAppend is alreasy synched
void rollOver() {
  File target;
  ...
```

Do we speak about the same thing : log4j-1.2.15 ?